# How to install Maven Plug in into My eclipse

Tags: eclipse

How to install Maven PLug into My eclipse

Actually i followed this way please  refer to the screen shots 
below

http://imageshack.us/f/405/31444757.jpg/

http://imageshack.us/f/13/32898163.jpg/

**Under Eclipse Find and  Install New Software i used below paths**

```
http://m2eclipse.codehaus.org/
http://m2eclipse.codehaus.org/update/
```

I am getting an error saying that  , It could not find the repository .

Please tell me how to resolve this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The plugin homepage (http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) states for this URL:

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases

Try it and luck!

Answer (score 2):

Please follow this:
**STEPS TO INSTALL MAVEN (in Eclipse)**:
Maven Eclipse plugin installation step by step:
  1.  Open Eclipse IDE

2. Click Help -> Install New Software...
3. Click Add button at top right corner
4. At pop up: fill up Name as "M2Eclipse" and Location as "http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases"

Now click OK After that installation would be started.

Another way to install Maven plug-in for Eclipse:

```
  1.    Open Eclipse

  2.    Go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace

  3.    Search by Maven

  4.    Click "Install" button at "Maven Integration for Eclipse" section

  5.    Follow the instruction step by step
```

*After successful installation do the followings in Eclipse:*
1.  Go to Window --> Preferences
2.  Observe, Maven is enlisted at left panel