# Maven build error: Unable to find resource 'javax.mail:mail:jar:1.3.3' in repository atlassian-contrib

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-mail

I'm building a project from **Confluence** sources (provided by client) but get the following error.

```
[INFO] Using default encoding to copy filtered resources.
Downloading: https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public/javax/mail/mail/1.3.3/mail-1.3.3.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'javax.mail:mail:jar:1.3.3' in repository atlassian-proxy (https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public)
Downloading: https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/contrib/javax/mail/mail/1.3.3/mail-1.3.3.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'javax.mail:mail:jar:1.3.3' in repository atlassian-contrib (https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/contrib)
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/mail/mail/1.3.3/mail-1.3.3.jar
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'javax.mail:mail:jar:1.3.3' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[INFO]    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO]    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Missing:
----------
1) javax.mail:mail:jar:1.3.3

  Try downloading the file manually from:
  http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/downloads/index.html

  Then, install it using the command:
  mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=javax.mail -DartifactId=mail    -Dversion=1.3.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file

  Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there:
  mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=javax.mail -DartifactId=mail -Dversion=1.3.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]

  Path to dependency:
    1) com.atlassian.xwork:atlassian-xwork-core:jar:1.13
    2) opensymphony:webwork:jar:2.1.5
    3) javax.mail:mail:jar:1.3.3

----------
1 required artifact is missing.

for artifact:
  com.atlassian.xwork:atlassian-xwork-core:jar:1.13

from the specified remote repositories:
  atlassian-proxy (https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  atlassian-contrib (https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/contrib)
```

But before it I run the following **maven** script to create necessary sub-folder in maven **repository**.

```
F:\Java\java-dev\Confluence\confluence-5.3.4-source>mvn3 install:install-file -DgroupId=javax.mail -DartifactId=mail -Dversion=1.3.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=mail-1.3.3.jar -s "settings.xml" -Dmaven.repo.local=C:/Users/PC/.m2/repository
```

After that created the following folder and sub-folders like following.
[image]

And finally **settings.xml** file provided as an argument is the following

```
<settings>
<localRepository></localRepository>
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>atlassian-repositories</id>
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>atlassian-proxy</id>
                <name>Atlassian Maven 2 Proxy</name>
                <url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
            </repository>
            <repository>
                <id>atlassian-contrib</id>
                <name>Atlassian Contrib Repository</name>
                <url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/contrib</url>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
                <id>atlassian-proxy</id>
                <name>Atlassian Maven 2 Proxy</name>
                <url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
            </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
</profiles>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>atlassian-repositories</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>

<mirrors>
    <mirror>
        <id>glassfish-mirror</id>
        <name>Mirror for glassfish</name>
        <url>https://maven.atlassian.com/content/repositories/atlassian-3rdparty/</url>
        <mirrorOf>glassfish-repository</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
    <mirror>
        <id>laughing-panda-mirror</id>
        <name>Mirror for laughing panda</name>
        <url>https://m2proxy.atlassian.com/repository/public</url>
        <mirrorOf>laughing panda</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
</mirrors>
```

So, I guess that the problem is stupid enough (I'm not e maven expert) and experts offer can help to solve the problem.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
</dependency>
```

> Now there is new version for this artifact **javax.mail:mail:jar:1.3.3**
>
> New version is 
>   New Version **1.5.0-b01**

You can download here [mvn repo link](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail/1.5.0-b01)

And if you are facing issue in downlaoding dependancy you can follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31720448/1878022)

And this link will help you [installing maven plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28757626/1878022)

> **SOLUTION 2:**
>   Unzip javamail-1_3_3_01.zip and use the extracted jar file for your local repository installation.

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=javax.mail -DartifactId=mail 
-Dversion=1.3.3 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=mail.jar
```

Source [Confluence](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/Failed+to+Resolve+Artifact+-+Missing+javax.mail+When+Building+the+Distribution+Source+Code)

Comment: Yes, I know that newer version is exist, but in huge code is used 1.3.3 and I selected that one. But the save problem still exists. I thing the problem in other place. Thank anyway.

Comment: I tried this approach too. Moved *.jar file into current folder but not successful. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: after downloading and installing jar in your repo what error do you get?

Comment: The same, I did a many configurations but got the same error. Anyway I'm running build with your configuration anyway, to see helps it or no. By the way the bill takes 10-15 minutes for NON first time. For first time it also downloads a huge of jars for maven.

Comment: NOP, I got the same problem :(

Comment: @AshotKarakhanyan moving the jar to the current folder does not help maven. To install it into your local maven repository, run `mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-jar-file> -DgroupId=javax-mail -DartifactId=mail -Dversion=1.3.3 -Dpackaging=jar`

Comment: @Zoltán it run similar script and jar file appear in repository (see screenshot provided). The problem is that, that using build script it steel invisible.

Comment: try clean and then build

Comment: JavaMail 1.3.3 is 10 years old and was released before we started using Maven and publishing to the Maven repository.  You'll need to use the procedure above to manually install it into your local repository (although the groupId should be "javax.mail", which may explain why the above isn't working for you).  Note also that the current version is JavaMail 1.5.4, which you can find in the Maven Central repository or download [here](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem adding this additional **repository** to my **settings.xml** settings file. Thank you all for attempts to help.

```
<repository>
    <id>localrepo</id>
    <url>file://F:/Java/java-dev/Confluence/confluence-5.3.4-source/`pwd`/localrepo</url>
</repository>
```